Comparing a string generated by a latex macro
Trying to compare the results of a macro to some fixed string, but not getting anywhere. I tried using the \detokenize\expandafter, but that just shows the contents of the macro (as in showing the code itself).
The core of the code is as follows:
\NewDocumentCommand{\Indexing}{O{}}{%
    \edef\ParsedIndexingList{\CheckListHasTokens[,][:]{#1}}%
    \typeout{ParsedIndexingList = \ParsedIndexingList} % Debugging line to output to the console/log
    \ifx\ParsedIndexingList\EmptyList\relax
        YES~(EmptyList)
    \else\ifx\ParsedIndexingList\AllToken\relax
        YES~(AllToken)
    \else\ifx\ParsedIndexingList\SomeToken\relax
        NO~(SomeToken)
    \else\ifx\ParsedIndexingList\NoToken\relax
        NO~(NoToken)
    \else
        NO~(Other)
    \fi\fi\fi\fi
}

The purpose of the \Indexing is to have formatting control depending on what indices are set.
The \CheckListHasTokens takes a string, splits it by #1 and checks if any of the elements in the result are #2 (see repro code below).
Result + What I expected

The debug log shows
...
ParsedIndexingList = \CheckListHasTokens [,][:]{}
ParsedIndexingList = \CheckListHasTokens [,][:]{}
ParsedIndexingList = \CheckListHasTokens [,][:]{i}
ParsedIndexingList = \CheckListHasTokens [,][:]{:,:}
ParsedIndexingList = \CheckListHasTokens [,][:]{i,j}
...

Code to repro
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% List token checks
% Four possible tokens are returned:
%   -EmptyList- ==> The list is empty, such as ""
%   -NoToken-   ==> No token is found, such as "abc" or "a,b,c"
%   -SomeToken- ==> Some, but not all elements are token, such as "<token>,b"
%   -AllToken-  ==> List only contains tokens, such as "<token>" or "<token>,<token>"
\NewDocumentCommand{\CheckListHasTokens}{O{,}O{:}m}{%
    \ifthenelse{\isempty{#3}}{%
        \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpb_tl {-EmptyList-}%
    }{%
        \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq {#1} {#3}%
        \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int {0} % Initialize the matching token counter
        \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {%
            \ifthenelse{\equal{##1}{#2}}{%
                \int_incr:N \l_tmpa_int % Increment counter if the token matches
            }{}%
        }%
        % Decision making based on the counter values
        \int_compare:nNnTF {\l_tmpa_int} = {\seq_count:N \l_tmpa_seq} {
            \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpb_tl {-AllToken-} % All tokens match
        }{
            \int_compare:nNnTF {\l_tmpa_int} = {0} {
                \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpb_tl {-NoToken-} % No tokens match
            }{
                \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpb_tl {-SomeToken-} % Some tokens match
            }
        }
    }
    \tl_use:N \l_tmpb_tl% Output the result
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

% Define possible outputs
\def\EmptyList{-EmptyList-}%
\def\NoToken{-NoToken-}%
\def\SomeToken{-SomeToken-}%
\def\AllToken{-AllToken-}%

% Checks and parses the indices
\NewDocumentCommand{\Indexing}{O{}}{%
    \edef\ParsedIndexingList{\CheckListHasTokens[,][:]{#1}}%
    \typeout{ParsedIndexingList = \ParsedIndexingList} % Debugging line to output to the console/log
    \ifx\ParsedIndexingList\EmptyList\relax
        YES~(EmptyList)
    \else\ifx\ParsedIndexingList\AllToken\relax
        YES~(AllToken)
    \else\ifx\ParsedIndexingList\SomeToken\relax
        NO~(SomeToken)
    \else\ifx\ParsedIndexingList\NoToken\relax
        NO~(NoToken)
    \else
        NO~(Other)
    \fi\fi\fi\fi
}
\begin{document}

\section*{CheckListHasTokens}
\par\noindent Direct output (should see -EmptyList-): \CheckListHasTokens[,][:]{}
\par\noindent Direct output (should see -NoToken-): \CheckListHasTokens[,][a]{b,b,b}
\par\noindent Direct output (should see -SomeToken-): \CheckListHasTokens[,][a]{a,b,b}
\par\noindent Direct output (should see -AllToken-): \CheckListHasTokens[,][a]{a,a,a}

\section*{Indexing}
\par\noindent Should output YES~(EmptyList): \Indexing           %
\par\noindent Should output YES~(EmptyList): \Indexing[]         %
\par\noindent Should output NO~(NoToken): \Indexing[i]        %
\par\noindent Should output YES~(AllToken): \Indexing[:,:]      %
\par\noindent Should output NO~(NoToken): \Indexing[i,j]      %

\end{document}

Update 1: The intent behind the \Indexing
This is an attempt to generalize indexing for tensors. In my case, the formatting is different depending on what arguments there are. Below is the way I do it now + the expected result.
The problem with the current implementation is that it assumes a 2 dimensional tensor. I was attempting to have a generic way of indexing, by providing an optional argument in a format [i,j,:,k]

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsfit}{T1}{\sfdefault}{\mddefault}{\sldefault}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathsfit}{bold}{T1}{\sfdefault}{\bfdefault}{\sldefault}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Tensor}{mO{:}O{:}}{\ensuremath{
    \ifboolexpr{
            test {\ifstrequal{#2}{:}}
        and test {\ifstrequal{#3}{:}}
    }
    {\pmb{\mathsf{#1}}}% Full tensor, no indexing
    {%
        \ifboolexpr{
                test {\ifstrequal{#2}{:}}
            or  test {\ifstrequal{#3}{:}}
        }
        {\pmb{#1}_{#2,#3}}% Part of a tensor
        {{#1}_{#2,#3}}% Single tensor element
    }
}}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item[{\Tensor{A}}] Full tensor \verb+\Tensor{A}+ \\
    \item[{\Tensor{A}[:][:]}] Full tensor \verb+\Tensor{A}[:][:]+ \\
    \item[{\Tensor{A}[:][j]}] Part of the tensor \verb+\Tensor{A}[:][j]+ \\
    \item[{\Tensor{A}[i]}] Part of the tensor \verb+\Tensor{A}[i]+ \\
    \item[{\Tensor{A}[i][j]}] Single element in the tensor \verb+\Tensor{A}[i][j]+ \\
\end{itemize}
\end{document}


\edef\ParsedIndexingList{\CheckListHasTokens[,][:]{#1}}% can not do anything useful as \CheckListHasTokens  is a protected command  so does not expand in an edef.

tbh, I don't know what that means, but after looking through the SO, I tried using \protected@edef\ParsedIndexingList{\CheckListHasTokens[,][:]{#1}}, which also didn't do much. Not sure if this is relevant

it's rather hard to guess the actual use case here as the code is a wild mix of primitive ifx tests, \ifthenelse (eek don't use that)  and expl3

No you simply can't expand that command, it does not "return a string" it is a sequence of assignments and other things that if executed, would typeset some text.

Got it, thank you! As far as the mix of if things -- yea, this is probably version 200 of trying different ways of comparing. The \Indexing is intended to be used to format some math notation based on existence of the indices. Let me add a note on that in the question, in case it helps

Added the minimum code describing how and why I am trying to compare the string

your use of 'token' is really confusing. <token>,b where is three tokens (if we assume <token> is a single token): <token>, , and b. as far as I can tell : is a 'token' in your sense. is anything else?

@cfr Not sure I understood the question. If you are asking what the <token> is, it's just any possible token that could represent "empty" indexing. In numpy/torch context it would be :, but in another context we use * as a wildcard. In numpy sense, indexing [:,:,:] is the same as []. Same goes for the * wildcard

in tex terms, b and , are tokens (the input stream is a stream of tokens), so using 'token' to mean something else is bound to confuse things.

If the optional argument is supposed to be a comma separated list of items, you can exploit expl3.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fixcmex}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsfit}{OT1}{\sfdefault}{\mddefault}{\sldefault}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathsfit}{bold}{OT1}{\sfdefault}{\bfdefault}{\sldefault}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\Tensor}{mo}
 {
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}
   {\bm{\mathsfit{#1}}}
   {\rafazz_tensor:nn {#1}{#2}}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \rafazz_tensor:nn
 {
  % let's check whether the clist #2 only consists of colons
  \str_set:Ne \l_tmpa_str { \clist_use:nn {#2} {} }
  \str_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_str {:} {}
  \str_if_empty:NTF \l_tmpa_str
   {% only colons
    \bm{\mathsfit{#1}}
   }
   {% not just colons
    \bm{\mathsfit{#1}} \c_math_subscript_token {\clist_use:nn {#2} {,}}
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item $\Tensor{A}$ Full tensor \verb+\Tensor{A}+

\item $\Tensor{A}[:]$ Full tensor \verb+\Tensor{A}[:]+

\item $\Tensor{A}[:,:,:]$ Full tensor \verb+\Tensor{A}[:,:,:]+

\item $\Tensor{A}[:,j]$ Part of the tensor \verb+\Tensor{A}[:,j]+

\item $\Tensor{A}[i,:]$ Part of the tensor \verb+\Tensor{A}[i,:]+

\item $\Tensor{A}[i,:,k,l]$ Part of the tensor \verb+\Tensor{A}[i,:,k,l]+

\item $\Tensor{A}[i,j,k,l]$ Single element in the tensor \verb+\Tensor{A}[i,j,k,l]+
\end{itemize}

\end{document}

I use lmodern in order to have boldface slanted sans (and fixcmex for large symbols). Note that I avoid \pmb that should only be used, if ever, in strict emergency.
The optional argument is examined; when the items are delivered in
\str_set:Ne \l_tmpa_str { \clist_use:nn {#2} {} }

spaces around commas are ignored. Then colons are replaced by nothing and, if the resulting string is empty, we know that only colons (or spaces) were used.

Two words of advice. First, items in itemize don't need \\ at the end; a blank line or nothing at all are as good. Second, you gain nothing at all with \ensuremath.

Thank you for the advice!

What we can do in OpTeX:
\fontfam[lm]

\newif\ifcolonsonly
\def\Tensor#1{{\bi A}\isnextchar[{\TensorIndex}{}}
\def\TensorIndex[#1]{\colonsonlytrue 
   \foreach #1,\do ##1,{\unless\ifx:##1\colonsonlyfalse\fi}
   \ifcolonsonly \else _{#1}\fi
}

$\Tensor A$ Full tensor A

$\Tensor A[:]$ Full tensor A[:],

$\Tensor A[:,:,:]$ Full tensor A[:,:,:],

$\Tensor A[:,j]$ Part of the tensor A[:,j],

$\Tensor A[i,:]$ Part of the tensor A[i,:],

$\Tensor A[i,:,k,l]$ Part of the tensor A[i,:,k,l],

$\Tensor A[i,j,k,l]$ Single element in the tensor A[i,j,k,l].

\bye

